# How to select only Nurbs curves in scene with Python in Maya (without objects in hierarchy)

Tags: python, maya, curve, nurbs

Suggest please a method to select all Nurbs curves in the Maya scene using Python. But I must select only curves without any other objects in the hierarchy before or after.
For example, I have a hierarchy like this:

Group
|NurbsCurve1
|Group
|NurbsCurve2...

I've tried this

```
cmds.ls(et = "nurbsCurve", ni = True, o = True, r = True)
```

This code selects the whole hierarchy including "Group"
But I need to select only NURBS curves without groups in the hierarchy.
How can I do this with Python code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out how to do it myself

```
All_curves = cmds.ls(type='nurbsCurve', ni=True, o=True, r=True, l = True)
curves_transforms = cmds.listRelatives(All_curves, p=True, type = "transform")
cmds.select(curves_transforms)
```

everything works